# How to use CreateUri method from UrlMon.dll in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I need to use [CreateUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms775098(v=vs.85).aspx) method from UrlMon.dll (...\Windows\System32) in C#, but i cant as the last parameter is IUri, which is also in UriMon.dll and i dont know how to use it.

I cant add this dll as reference or get IUri type with Assembly.GetType().

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to use CreateUri?

Comment: I have list if URIs and i need to check which of them use top level domains(TLDs). the list of TLDs is also in UrlMon.dll and there must be way to check it by using public API of this dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
public enum UriProperty
{
    ABSOLUTE_URI = 0,
    STRING_START = ABSOLUTE_URI,
    AUTHORITY = 1,
    DISPLAY_URI = 2,
    DOMAIN = 3,
    EXTENSION = 4,
    FRAGMENT = 5,
    HOST = 6,
    PASSWORD = 7,
    PATH = 8,
    PATH_AND_QUERY = 9,
    QUERY = 10,
    RAW_URI = 11,
    SCHEME_NAME = 12,
    USER_INFO = 13,
    USER_NAME = 14,
    STRING_LAST = USER_NAME,
    HOST_TYPE = 15,
    DWORD_START = HOST_TYPE,
    PORT = 16,
    SCHEME = 17,
    ZONE = 18,
    DWORD_LAST = ZONE
}

[ComImport]
[Guid("A39EE748-6A27-4817-A6F2-13914BEF5890"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IUri
{
    UInt32 GetPropertyBSTR([In]UriProperty uriProp, [Out]out string strProperty, [In]UInt32 dwFlags);
    UInt32 GetPropertyLength([In]UriProperty uriProp, [Out] out UInt32 pcPropLen, [In]UInt32 dwFlags);
    UInt32 GetPropertyDWORD([In]UriProperty uriProp, [Out] out UInt32 pcPropValue, [In]UInt32 dwFlags);
    UInt32 HasProperty([In]UriProperty uriProp, [Out] out bool fHasProperty);
    UInt32 GetAbsoluteUri([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sAbsoluteUri);
    UInt32 GetAuthority([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sAuthority);
    UInt32 GetDisplayUri([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sDisplayString);
    UInt32 GetDomain([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sDomain);
    UInt32 GetExtension([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sExtension);
    UInt32 GetFragment([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sFragment);
    UInt32 GetHost([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sHost);
    UInt32 GetPassword([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sPassword);
    UInt32 GetPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sPath);
    UInt32 GetPathAndQuery([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sPathAndQuery);
    UInt32 GetQuery([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sQuery);
    UInt32 GetRawUri([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sRawUri);
    UInt32 GetSchemeName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sSchemeName);
    UInt32 GetUserInfo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sUserInfo);
    UInt32 GetUserName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][Out] out string sUserName);
    UInt32 GetHostType([Out] uint dwHostType);
    UInt32 GetPort([Out] uint dwPort);
    UInt32 GetScheme([Out] uint dwScheme);
    UInt32  GetZone([Out] uint dwZone);
    UInt32 GetProperties([Out] uint dwFlags);
    UInt32 IsEqual([In]IUri pUri,[Out] bool fEqual);
}
```

This gives us IUri interface and now we can use CreateUri method:

```
[DllImport("UrlMon.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool CreateUri(string uri, uint flag, IntPtr dwReserved, out IUri a);
```